# Lowercase 301 Redirects - Site Assets Disappear

Tags: htaccess, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am trying to force all my URLs to be lowercase, but in doing so, I lose the connection to all my site assets.

I've added this to my  in my .conf file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

And this to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

This is added before my final index.php declaration within the mod_rewrite area of the .htaccess

I'll post my full htaccess to view.
http://pastebin.com/PsSsVVeR

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
I apologise, but I'm relatively new at apache configuration.

Comment: Apache and Linux are case sensitive. So if a directory/file is *example.com/hoG/heaVEn*, then the HTTP request would have to match. As as matter of consistency, most people create their site with all lowercase but not always. Check your directory names and file names for mixed case.

Comment: closetnoc has a point, although I had assumed (before answering below) that you'd already checked that directly requested lowercase URLs already functioned correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is where you have placed these directives in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# New directives inserted...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
```

The first 3 `RewriteCond` directives should apply to the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` directive - to prevent your *site assets* (files that exist) from being rewritten - but you've stuck your new directives in the middle! `RewriteCond` directives apply to the *single* `RewriteRule` that follows. As it is now, all your *site assets* are going to be redirected (internally rewritten) to `index.php` - which will make them "disappear"!

Try moving your two directives to the top of your .htaccess file (after you've enabled the `RewriteEngine`).

Comment: Great spot! Thanks for this. However, I've done so, but if I try and redirect to `/admin` for example, (which is lowercase, and redirects to another, lowecase url) I'm redirected to `/%5bl%5d` which is bizarre. Can you help.

Comment: Actually, I think I've found the source of my issues, but it goes deeper than I thought, so I'll mark you as correct (as in essence, it does solve my issue in a nutshell)